# Downloaded Windows 7 32-bit has bootmgr.efi file missing

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation

Recently I downloaded Windows 7 32-bit. However, I am unable to load it onto a USB drive by using the Windows 7 USB DVD download tool.

It gives a message that the iso is not valid. I then found that `bootmgr.efi` is missing in the downloaded file. How can I proceed to fix this and format my laptop?

Comment: P.S.- Efi is not supported, I got that. But the issue regarding uploading the windows ISO file still remains. Any idea..?

Comment: You can’t install Windows from a USB hard drive using AT BIOS. It seems to be a limitation of the Windows setup bootloader.

Comment: @kinokijuf   The phrase you use, "AT BIOS" is a very unusual phrase.. It  doesn't get much on Google.   wikipedia doesn't mention it. It mentions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer/AT   The IBM AT computer  .    Also, the original IBM PC was not the IBM AT en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer   Some mention the IBM PC/AT BIOS.. But then why not just call it IBM PC BIOS.?

Comment: @barlop I don't know which model introduced this type of BIOS, but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS “The BIOS of the original IBM PC and XT had no interactive user interface.” I think i was following Windows when i wrote that, which calls the two types of BIOSes it supports “PCAT” and “EFI” (note: _not_ “UEFI”)

Answer (score 0):

32-bit Windows does not support EFI.

Comment: 32Bit Windows **7** doesn't support UEFI, but win8 does support it.